# Would upgrade destroy my home folder?

Tags: upgrade, home-directory

I have at the moment ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS installed and planning on installing 13.04.

I have my root('/') mounted on one partition and my home('/home') on other partition.

If I would upgrade through normal installation(live usb/cd with format of '/' ) and set installation paramaters(same user,same computer name,same password,'/' on one partition and '/home' on other partition) like my old one, would it keep my /home directory intact?

I know if I would reinstall same version of ubuntu it won't break anything,but don't know nothing if I upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the upgrade in the way you described it.
Important is, that you do not format your home-partition, but the root-partition.

BUT:

- Ubuntu 13.04 is not released yet and could be unstable!
- It is absolutely recommended to create a backup!
  Sometimes anything goes wrong and you will have the risk of a data loss.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies,one more thing tough,what happens if I choose not to format '/' partition?

Comment: I think the installer will try to overwrite the data - this is inadvisable. You will have new and old data mixed. Or the install will fail. But I dont tested it so far.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't tell something to format the /home partition, then it will not be formatted :)
The upgrade process will only update system files and not your own data. Beware if some software configuration format or options has changed though, since ~/.config will remain unchanged.